# Bokeh: minimal app with custom template+CSS?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm running a Bokeh app similar to the stocks example:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/stocks

That example does not have any html files that can be customized. I'd like to modify it such that I have an html template where I can add my custom CSS styles. Templates are mentioned at:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

but I couldn't find a complete working example. Is there a ***complete minimal working example*** available somewhere for a reference? Can somebody share one?

I'm using `bokeh serve .` to run the app now. Do I have to run it differently when I put an html template in place?

On a related note, there is an example for adding CSS styles from within the app (JS called from Python) provided at: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/ZZ7fhq9OziQ. Is there a simpler, cleaner solution that accomplished the same goal (with no hidden, dummy widgets)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of examples in the bokeh gallery which use templates, some also using external css files.

See https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/gapminder
for example.

Here is a small bokeh app example i wrote, which makes use of external css and a template file: 
https://gist.github.com/anthonydouc/c8571f0a2f9aa8415bd566e1ac2ba237.

With these examples if you store all of the code in the folder myapp, 
run the command `bokeh serve myapp` to start the server.

Comment: How can I add another template file(second.html) along with index.html?

Comment: Without making any changes, only a single page app is supported. However, you could launch multiple applications or embed multiple bokeh server applications within a larger web app.